# How to await on an Subject.next in RXJS?

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

I've a component that I'm currently unit-testing.
This component takes a service as input. This services provides an observable.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    private _subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private someService:SomeService){
    }
    
    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription = this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(async v=>await this.doSomethingWithValue(v));
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    
    async doSomethingWithValue(v){
        await this.someService.doSomeAsyncCall();
        //...   
    }   
}

export class SomeService{
    public someObservable:Observable<string>;
    
    constructor(){
        this.someObservable = //subscription to multiple other services, transformations and consolidation.
    }
    
    async doSomeAsyncCall(){
        await something...
    }
}
```

To unit test it, I need to mock this observable(currently using `ng-mocks`, but same issue would also happen with other tests.

```
it('should update correctly when XYZ', async ()=> {
    
    const notifications = new Subject<string>();
    MockInstance(SomeService, 'someObservable', notifications.asObservable());  
    const component = MockRender(SomeComponent).point.componentInstance;
    
    notifications.next('something');
    
    expect(something);//This is being called before the `doSomethingWithValue` get called
    
})
```

My issue is that my `expect` being instantly after the `notification.next`, before the execution of `doSomethingWithValue`.

I cannot wait on `notifications.next(...)`, because it doesn't returns observable or promise.

How would you ensure all async call behind any `Subject` have been properly awaited? This happens with a test but also could happens in non-test code.

And obviously, the goal is not to wait on a random amount of time that would not always work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-fakeasync) with the `tick` function to simulate async scenarios:

```js
it('should update correctly when XYZ', fakeAsync(() => {
    
    const notifications = new Subject<string>();
    MockInstance(SomeService, 'someObservable', notifications.asObservable());  
    const component = MockRender(SomeComponent).point.componentInstance;
    
    notifications.next('something');
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    expect(something);    
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. First issue, this only work in the context of a unit test, but my issue can happens in other context. Also, does `tick` make sense if there is no `setTimeout` involved?